# URL will not redirect (Android)

Tags: android, .htaccess, http, redirect, soundcloud

I'm trying to get the JSON from a redirected page, but the code right now refuses to follow the redirect, even though I've specifically requested that it follow redirects within the code. Since this is Android, I'm running this function on a background thread. It's working up to the point where I try to redirect, at which point it gets stuck on the 'resolve URL' (for more information on this particular URL look here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve). Here is the method:

```
class SoundcloudTrackIDAsyncTasker extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(URL... params) {
        try {

            URLConnection newURLConnection = params[0].openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection conn =  (HttpURLConnection) newURLConnection;
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true); // fails, regardless if true or false
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true); // same
            newURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream newURLConnectedStream = newURLConnection.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("" + newURLConnection);
            URL tracksURL =
                    new URL(newURLConnection + "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID);
            URLConnection trackURLConnection = tracksURL.openConnection();
            trackURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream trackURLConnectionInputStream = trackURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader readHTTPStream = new InputStreamReader(trackURLConnectionInputStream,
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            //read the track ID and return it.
            JSONURL urlAsJson = gson.fromJson(readHTTPStream, JSONURL.class);
            return urlAsJson.getTrack();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false); ... false?

Comment: @WilliMentzel Sorry, that should say true...but I get the same error whether it's true or false

Comment: I updated your code to avoid confusion